# php turning /tmp/ file to a $_FILE

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have JS uploading to PHP which creates a /tmp/ file. Then JS lets the user to edit the meta data to send back to the API.

The JS then sends back to my php API:

"image":"@/tmp/test.jpg"

From that, I would like to invoke a $_FILES['image'] object to copy and move_uploaded_file with

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that's impossible. The very purpose of move_uploaded_file() function is to check if the file were really uploaded, not faked by some API.

You can use copy() instead but make sure you took all the precautions.

Comment: Is it possible to load a local image file as some sort of object to work with? EG:

$image = fopen($sentData['image_path']); copy($image, 'somewhere/test.jpg');

?

Answer (score 1):

For uploaded files, the manual states:

```
The file will be deleted from the temporary directory
at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.
```

So you can move_uploaded_file to your custom temporary directory and respond to your client-side application with a new file name. Then you will probably need to write a script which cleans your temporary directory at some time (using cron)